# "Fenstertag" vs. "Brückentag"

Tags: noun, regional

Heute am 24.06.2011 ist in Bayern ein [Brückentag](http://www.feiertage-newsletter.de/deutschland/brueckentage-2011.html), da gestern ein Feiertag (Fronleichnam) war.

Brückentage sind einzelne Tage, die zwischen einem Feiertag und dem Wochenende liegen und an denen gerne Urlaub genommen wird.

Ich habe auch schon die Bezeichnung „Fenstertag“ gehört, die bei manchen Gesprächspartnern aber Irritationen hervorruft: „Ach so, du meinst Brückentage!“

Gibt es Gegenden, in denen *Fenstertag* die gebräuchliche Bezeichnung ist?

Comment: Noch _nie_ gehört!

Comment: Auch noch nie gehört, aber wohl [gültig](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%BCckentag): `In Österreich, insbesondere in Oberösterreich, ist neben der Bezeichnung Fenstertag auch die Bezeichnung Zwickeltag verbreitet.`

Comment: @Pekka: ich bin aus Oberösterreich und mir ist vor allem Zwickeltag geläufig. Fenstertag habe ich vereinzelt schon gehört, halte ich aber hier für nicht sehr weit verbreitet.

Comment: Graz, Steiermark, Ö: Fenstertag ist im ausschließlichen Gebrauch. Zwickeltag war mir unbekannt, "Brückentag" kenne ich nur von "Zugereisten" aus Deutschland.

Comment: Was Onkel Dagobert auf der Nase trägt ist ein "Zwicker" und ein "Zwickel" war in Bayern eine 2 DM Münze und wird analog für den Euro auch gebraucht.

Comment: @RainerMergarten: Sollte dieser Kommentar nicht unter der [Antwort](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/1599/5999) stehen, als Reaktion auf einen der dortigen Kommentare?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ich habe ein paar Jahre lang in Wien gearbeitet. Dort war *"Fenstertag"* tatsächlich ein geläufiger Ausdruck für den Tag, der zwischen einem Feiertag und dem Wochenende liegt und von vielen als Urlaubstag genommen wird.

In Österreich hört man auch *"Zwickeltag"*. In Südtirol wird umgangssprachlich häufig das italienische Fremdwort *"Ponte"* verwendet, das *"Brücke"* bedeutet.

[Auf dieser Seite gibt es eine Karte](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-460-reise-at-Fenstertag.html), wo die Verbreitung des Begriffs dargestellt ist. [Hier für *Zwickeltag*](http://ostarrichi.org/oesterreich-5247-at-Zwickeltag.html).

Der Begriff *Zwickel* bezeichnet ein keilförmiges Stück; bei Kleidungsstücken kann es sich um einen keilförmigen Einsatz unter einem angeschnittenen Ärmel handeln, auch eine Strumpfhose kann einen Zwickel haben. In der Architektur bezeichnet man einen Übergang von einem mehreckigen Grundriss zu einer Kuppel als Zwickel. Auch die Wandfläche zwischen zwei Bögen einer Arkade wird so genannt.

Comment: Was aber hat es mit dem Fenster auf sich. Die Brücke als Verbindung zw. zwei Ufern ist ja unmittelbar einleuchtend. Zusatzfrage: Zwickeltag, dito. Ist Zwickel nicht eine Münze?

Comment: Ich dachte immer, ein Zwickel ist das, was Onkel Dagobert auf der Nase trägt... ^^ @Fenster: Naja, der Feiertag und das Wochenende bilden zwischen sich quasi ein "Fenster" und das ist der Fenstertag. Ein Zeitfenster eben. ;)

Comment: @splattne: Beide Links in deiner Antwort zweigen auf etwas, das nicht mit dem übereinstimmt was du im Text ankündigst. Zur Sache: »Brückentag« habe ich noch nie gehört. »Zwickeltag« kenne ich von einem aus Oberösterreich stammenden Freund und aus der Fernsehwerbung (XXXLutz bewirbt immer Sonderaktionen an diesen Tagen). In Graz und in Wien gehört aber der »Fenstertag« zum Standard-Wortschatz.

Answer (score 3):

Ich wurde 1965 in Graz geboren und bin dort aufgewachsen, habe einige Jahre in der Nähe von Leoben und Bruck/Mur gelebt und lebe seit 1997 in Wien.

### Brückentag

Diesen Begriff habe ich noch nie gehört, und gerade eben zum ersten Mal in meinem Leben gelesen. Dieser Begriff ist im Osten Österreichs völlig ungebräuchlich.

### Zwickeltag

Meiner Beobachtung nach stammt dieser Begriff aus Oberösterreich und der süd-östlichen Ecke Bayerns. In Wien und Graz war dieser Begriff lange Zeit unbekannt, und wurde nur von »eingewanderten« Oberösterreichern benutzt, die aber schnell lernten, dass man sie hier besser versteht wenn sie »Fenstertag« sagen.

Seit aber das Möbelhaus XXXLutz (gegründet von einem oberösterreichischen Ehepaar, Firmensitz in Wels in Oberösterreich) in seiner Fernsehwerbung an diesem Tagen mit besonderen Angeboten mit dem Slogan »Zwickeltage bei XXXLutz« wirbt, ist dieses Wort auch in ganz Österreich bekannt. In der Werbung ist nicht nur der Freitag nach einem freien Donnerstag gemeint, sondern auch der darauf folgende Samstag. Daher wird im Slogan der Plural verwendet. Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch ist ein Zwickeltag aber ein einzelner Tag, und das trifft auch auf die hier dargestellten Synonyme zu.

### Fenstertag

Das ist im Osten Österreichs der Standard-Begriff für einen arbeits-pflichtigen Freitag, der auf einen Feiertags-Donnerstag folgt, oder (seltener) ein arbeits-pflichtiger Montag, der einem Feiertags-Dienstag vorausgeht. Dieser Tag ist also ein Arbeits-Zeitfenster zwischen Tagen die arbeitsfrei sind. Und wenn man sich diesen Tag frei nimmt (was viele tun), öffnet sich dieses Fenster, und man hat mit nur einem Urlaubstag vier aufeinander folgende arbeitsfreie Tage (vorausgesetzt man muss Samstags nicht arbeiten).